# How to display a loading message before the ajax call starts?

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$('#wait').ajaxStart(function (){
$(this).css('background-position','0 -90px');
});
var result = $.ajax({
url: "file.php",
async: false,
data: ({id:id}),
type: "post",
cache: false
}).responseText;
```

The #wait div has a background with an ok, error and wait icons and I want to change the background position of the div BEFORE the ajax call stars, but it's not working. I've tried to alert something from the ajaxStart funcion and it worked, so I don't know from what reason the ajax does not wait for the background position change....

Comment: Have you tried with an asynchronous call? You should avoid synchronous calls anyway.

Comment: I think without async I can`t get back the result from the server

Comment: Of course you can.... otherwise what would be the sense of it? You have to set a `success` callback which gets called with the response passed as argument. Have a look at the jQuery documentation, there are examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your ajax request is synchronous, and javascript is single-threaded, it will block other activities. I'm not sure why your specific case does not work, since I would expect the `css` method to be completed immediately, but I expect it has to do with the specifics of when a browser actually renders updates the DOM, which may not happen until the thread is completed.

Generally speaking, though, you can avoid this problem entirely by using asynchronous requests. Blocking ajax requests can also create a negative user experience, because the UI is completely disabled while it's taking place. Because of this it's almost always preferable to use an async request. If you need to ensure that page elements are disabled (e.g., effectively simulating a synchronous request), there are plenty of jquery plugins to do this easily. I've had good luck with `blockui`: http://jquery.malsup.com/block/

Comment: my problem is that if I set async to true than the responseText is empty

Comment: It doesn't work the same way. See the last comment on your original question. You need to attach a callback to the `success` option. It's not difficult at all, it's just different, because it's asynchronous. The documentation http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ has a dead simple example about halfway down the page.

Answer (score 0):

[beforeSend(jqXHR, settings)Function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

A pre-request callback function that can be used to modify the jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHTTPRequest) object before it is sent. Use this to set custom headers, etc. The jqXHR and settings maps are passed as arguments. This is an Ajax Event. Returning false in the beforeSend function will cancel the request. As of jQuery 1.5, the beforeSend option will be called regardless of the type of request.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with the `beforeSend(jqXHR, settings)` function for the wait background, the `error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown`) for errors and the `success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)` function if the request succeeds ?

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with jQuery mobile trying to display the $.mobile.loading before i send data and in my case it has to go up sync. Some data must be uploaded before others so if if it was all async it may send up some update records before the inserts happen. My solution was to up at setTimeout around the ajax call so that i gave the loading time to show up before ajax fired. Sucky way to do it but until they give me a call back to $.mobile.loading I am stuck using it.